# gdb core file missing

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I used to use GDB to debug my C/C++ program. But after the server crashed and reinstalled, the GDB is not working properly. After the program reports a 'core dumped', actually the core file is not found. My flags to compile is:

```
CFLAGS=     -ggdb -g -pg -Wall -O2 $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 gthread-2.0 --cflags glib-2.0)
```

And I also set this:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

I already remove all object/executable files and recompile. But the core file is simply missing. Could anybody tell what is other probable reason? Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory) question might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine (Ubuntu 12.04), the file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` pipes the core dumped result to `/usr/share/apport/apport`:

```
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c
```

So changed to pattern:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo core.%e.%p > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'
```

It works.

Reference: [Unable to create a core file for my crashed program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760220/unable-to-create-a-core-file-for-my-crashed-program)