# I run `"crash_demo.run"` by `spawn-fcgi` . How to collect `core` file

Tags: c++, nginx, coredump, spawn-fcgi

#### 1. Question

I run `"crash_demo.run"` by `spawn-fcgi` .
How to collect `core` file .

#### 2. Background & Environment

I'm exolore C++ Web Programming .

1. web-server : nginx
2. CGI(FastCGI) : [fastcgipp 3.0](https://github.com/eddic/fastcgipp)
3. CGI Wrapper : spawn-fcgi

   - I didn't use [FCGI Wrap](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/) which ngifix supplied .
   - I understand `FCGI Wrap` be drive by spawn-fcgi , Of course this is off topic .
4. My c++ application . (be called `crash_demo`) .

#### 3. Step to reproduce exception

1. `crash_demo` insert code `throw "test exception str, check _core_ file"` , build got `crash_demo.run`
2. run nginx : `sudo nginx -c my_nginx_custom.config`
3. `ulimit -c unlimited`
4. run `crash_demo.run` by `spawn-fcgi` : `spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -f /path/crash_demo.run`
5. test the normal http request , and http request can be completed normally .
6. test the `crash_demo` http request , got `5xx` response .

   - The directory where `crash_demo.run` is located does not see the `core` file

My guess

1. `core` file not generate  .
2. `core` file is generated  , but i don't the file path .

Does anyone know what happened?

---

---

#### Solution update

My question is flawed .

Thanks @sehe , my step :

1. I read two webpage

   1. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html
   2. https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/240633280
2. [update my `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12760552/7707781)

   - `core` -> `core_%e_%p_%t`
3. `ulimit -c unlimited`
4. `spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -f /path/crash_demo.run`
5. `sudo find /  core_ | grep core_crash_demo`

   - result `/path/core_crash_demo._5080_1652169152`

So , my guess on my question is failed .

The fact is , I don't generate `core` file , when my question.

When my generated `core` file successed , the `core` file path is `crash_demo.run` parent directory .

---

---

#### Solution update 2

we whant to know two point :

1. how generate core dump file
2. how to  fine  exception code by core dump file

##### **how generate core dump file？**

Reference the file : [core manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)

core manual write many point , I just list the point i care :

1. system limit core dump file size , we need unlimit it:

- `ulimit -a` check limit   /   `ulimit -c unlimited` cancel limit

2. fix `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

- default value is `core`
- fix it to -> `core_%e_%p_%t` mean `core_your_execute_file_name_pid_timestemp`
- fix cmd : `sudo bash -c 'echo core_%e_%p_%t > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'`

now run your exception , you can got core file .

- maby you need search it : `sudo find /  core_ | grep core_`

##### **how to  fine  exception code by core dump file ？**

- I use vscode , fix `launch.json` , add `coreDumpPath` , refrence : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_memory-dump-debugging

Comment: I want get the crash core file .

Comment: [SO] is an English site. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines#:~:text=Articles%20must%20be%20in%20the%20primary%20language%20of%20the%20target%20site%20that%20they%20accompany%20(currently%20English%2C%20since%20collectives%20%22accompany%22%20the%20main%20SO%20site%3B%20if%20there%27s%20ever%20a%20collective%20for%20another%20site%2C%20like%20the%20Russian%20SO%20site%2C%20it%20must%20be%20in%20the%20primary%20language%20of%20that%20site).)

Comment: @sehe yes , so i write one question twice by two language .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably more for askubuntu.com or serverfault.stackexchange.com.

You likely need to configure core dump. Since we don't know the platform, I'm assuming likely a Linux. See e.g. [core(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20various%20circumstances%20in%20which%20a%20core%20dump%20file%20is%20not%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20produced):

> There are various circumstances in which a core dump file is not
> produced

In my experience what's required is setting a core pattern (`/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`)